# Use empty list as guard clause

Tags: erlang

I'm starting with erlang and I have started with some simple exercises. In this case I'm trying to calculate the Gauss' triangle row. I don't understand why I'm getting this warning:

```
Warning: this clause cannot match because a previous clause at line 6 always matches
```

The problem is related with the guard clause but it's seems legit to me xD. Following is the complete code:

```
create_row(Initial)->create_row(Initial,[1]).

create_row([First|Rest],Current) -> 
    io:format("rest size: ~w ~n",[Rest]),
    create_row(Rest,lists:append(Current,[First+lists:nth(1, Rest)]));

create_row([_|Rest],Current) when length(Rest)==0 -> lists:append(Current,[1]).
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 2 patterns for the `create_row/2` function in this order:

```
create_row([First|Rest],Current) ->
```

and

```
create_row([_|Rest],Current) when length(Rest)==0 ->
```

The patterns are matched in order. The first pattern will match all the cases the second does an so the second will never get executed.

If you reverse the order of the functions, it should work:

```
create_row([_|Rest],Current) when length(Rest)==0 -> 
  lists:append(Current,[1]);
create_row([First|Rest],Current) -> 
  io:format("rest size: ~w ~n",[Rest]),
  create_row(Rest,lists:append(Current,[First+lists:nth(1, Rest)])).
```

Now the first function will only match those with length 0 and second will match the rest.

Note that most specific functions should go on top.

Comment: Ok!! I didn't know that!!, so now all have sense. I thought that the function order haven't any impact.

Answer (score 4):

Although, the reason for warning message is described in [Asier Azkuenaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1065399)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43248605/49197)

```
create_row([_|Rest],Current) when length(Rest)==0 ->
```

is a less efficient equivalent of

```
create_row([_],Current) ->
```

And

```
lists:nth(1, Rest)
```

is a less efficient equivalent of

```
hd(Rest)
```

Anyway, you are probably looking for:

```
create_row([]) -> [1];
create_row([H|T])->
    [H | create_row(H, T)].

create_row(X, [H|T]) ->
    [X+H | create_row(H, T)];
create_row(X, []) -> [X].
```

You are making Pascal's triangle, right?

```
18> test:create_row([]).
[1]
19> test:create_row(v(-1)).
[1,1]
20> test:create_row(v(-1)).
[1,2,1]
21> test:create_row(v(-1)).
[1,3,3,1]
22> test:create_row(v(-1)).
[1,4,6,4,1]
23> test:create_row(v(-1)).
[1,5,10,10,5,1]
24> test:create_row(v(-1)).
[1,6,15,20,15,6,1]
25> test:create_row(v(-1)).
[1,7,21,35,35,21,7,1]
26> test:create_row(v(-1)).
[1,8,28,56,70,56,28,8,1]
```

BTW, your code is O(N^2) due to appending at the end of accumulator `Current`.

Comment: wow! your implementation is nice!! I still have a long path to follow in erlang :)

Comment: @rdiaz82: I have added more efficient and elegant version.

Comment: Note that the `v(-1)` is a shell command that refers to the result of the previous command.